# How can the router path be accessed by html in "Django rest framework"?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build a simple blog in Django Rest Framework.
I want to add like count by pressing the button on the list page to send post method to the server.

This is views.py

```
class BlogListView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer
    renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer, TemplateHTMLRenderer]

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = request.user
        like_id = request.POST.get('pk', None)
        add_like = Like.objects.get(pk=like_id)

        if add_like.likes.filter(id=user.id).exists():
            add_like.likes.remove(user)
        else:
            add_like.likes.add(user)

        context = {'likes_count': add_like.total_likes}
        serializer = BlogSerializer(context)
        return Response(serializer, content_type='application/json')
```

This is url.

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('dashboard', views.BlogListView, basename='dashboard')

app_name = 'blog'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

This is HTML.

```
<button type="button" class="like" name="{{ like.id }}">
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.('.like').click(function () {
      var pk = $(this).attr('name');
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "{% url 'blog:dashboard' %}",
          data: {'pk': pk, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (response) {
              id = $(this).attr('name');
              $('#count'+pk).html('count: ' + response.likes_count);
              alert('success');
          },
          error: function (request.status.error) {
              alert('error');
          }
      });
  })
</script>
```

But this url spits out this error.

```
Reverse for 'dashboard' not found. 'dashboard' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

How can I get this resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a ViewSet, which has different actions (like list, update, retrieve).

Instead of `{% url 'blog:dashboard' %}`, you should use `{% url 'blog:dashboard-list' %}`

See: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#usage